# How to print the Contents of a Panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing

How do I print the contents of a panel in vb.net, VS-2010 Winform.

I tried the code provided [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=559556) but for some reason its not working.

I am trying to print the Form inside the panel

[image]

Comment: I see no reason looping through the controls within the panel would not do exactly what you want.  You say its not working but do not go into detail of what it is doing exactly.  This is a very basic concept....

Comment: @Ramhound, can you put up an example code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Print in VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776452/how-to-print-in-vb-net)

Comment: Hey Stop Down-voting , if my rep goes below 10 then i wont be able to upload images in my questions.

Comment: Hey stop posting duplicate questions. If you post too many of them, you won't be able to post questions at all. The better strategy is to go back and edit your original question to include new information and better images.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I have already posted this question. Its been a very busy day for me, its hard to keep everything in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32" ( _
         ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
         ByVal Msg As Integer, _
         ByVal wParam As IntPtr, _
         ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
Private Enum EDrawingOptions As Integer
    PRF_CHECKVISIBLE = &H1
    PRF_NONCLIENT = &H2
    PRF_CLIENT = &H4
    PRF_ERASEBKGND = &H8
    PRF_CHILDREN = &H10
    PRF_OWNED = &H20
End Enum

Private Function PrintPanel()
 Const WM_PRINT As Integer = &H317

    Dim myBmp As Bitmap
    Dim myGraphics As Graphics
    Dim hdc As System.IntPtr

    myBmp = New Bitmap( _
        Me.FormsDispPanel.DisplayRectangle.Width, _
        Me.FormsDispPanel.DisplayRectangle.Height)

    myGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBmp)
    myGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, New Rectangle(0, 0,      
  Me.FormsDispPanel.DisplayRectangle.Width, Me.FormsDispPanel.DisplayRectangle.Height))
    hdc = myGraphics.GetHdc
  '"FormsDispPanel" is your PAnel to print
    Call SendMessage(FormsDispPanel.Handle, WM_PRINT, hdc, _
        EDrawingOptions.PRF_CHILDREN Or _
        EDrawingOptions.PRF_CLIENT Or _
        EDrawingOptions.PRF_NONCLIENT Or _
        EDrawingOptions.PRF_OWNED)

    myGraphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc)

    myBmp.Save("d:\out.bmp")

    myGraphics.Dispose()
    myGraphics = Nothing

    myBmp = Nothing
    End Function
```